# error deploying war file to payara micro

Tags: java, payara, payara-micro

I am trying to track down the following exception, running payara micro

`java -jar payara-micro-5.182.jar --deplay mywar.war`

It seems to be some kind of internal error, some pointers on what parts of my application might be causing this would be of great help.

```
[2018-07-17T15:04:27.730+0200] [] [?[1;92mINFO?[0m] [] [?[1;94mcom.bmw.pcc.configuration.ApplicationStartup?[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1531832667730] [levelValue: 800] loading settings...  
[2018-07-17T15:04:28.827+0200] [] [?[1;92mINFO?[0m] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [?[1;94mjavax.enterprise.web?[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1531832668827] [levelValue: 800] Loading application [pcc] at [/]    
[2018-07-17T15:04:29.179+0200] [] [?[1;93mWARNING?[0m] [NCLS-CORE-00069] [?[1;94mjavax.enterprise.system.core?[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1531832669179] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Exception while dispatching an event
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at fish.payara.microprofile.openapi.impl.processor.ApplicationProcessor.visitProduces(ApplicationProcessor.java:315)
        at fish.payara.microprofile.openapi.impl.visitor.OpenApiWalker.processAnnotation(OpenApiWalker.java:217)
        at fish.payara.microprofile.openapi.impl.visitor.OpenApiWalker.processAnnotations(OpenApiWalker.java:193)
        at fish.payara.microprofile.openapi.impl.visitor.OpenApiWalker.processAnnotations(OpenApiWalker.java:206)
        at fish.payara.microprofile.openapi.impl.visitor.OpenApiWalker.accept(OpenApiWalker.java:173)
        at fish.payara.microprofile.openapi.impl.processor.ApplicationProcessor.process(ApplicationProcessor.java:157)
        at fish.payara.microprofile.openapi.impl.OpenApiService.createOpenApiDocument(OpenApiService.java:186)
        at fish.payara.microprofile.openapi.impl.OpenApiService.event(OpenApiService.java:151)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
```

Perhaps I can disable `OpenApi` (assuming it's only used to provide documentation)

> How do I disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in 5.182 and will be fixed in 5.183. Until then, you can disable OpenAPI scanning with `mp.openapi.scan.disable` property. For example:

```
java -jar -Dmp.openapi.scan.disable=true payara-micro.jar
```